# Matplotlib opens but not responding

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, conda

I have a plot function below. It was working on miniconda successdully but this morning I had to uninstalled and reinstalled miniconda. Then I installed necessary libraries. PyQt5 works fine but when I call this function with a button, the plot window opens but not responding.

I even tried the same code on a normal Python (not miniconda) and same result happens.

My editor is Geany and Pyzo.

I add `plt.ion` but no success.

My libraries

Python 3.6.5

matplotlib 2.2.2 py36h153e9ff_1

pyqt 5.9.2 py36h1aa27d4_0

conda 4.5.8 py36_0

I editted my code. This is working but it is not working by calling it from a button.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

def PlotDistanceToHome():
    """ Plot Distance To Home (m) """
    TimeMin = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    DistanceToHome = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    PlotFunction(TimeMin,
                        'Zaman (dk)',
                        [DistanceToHome],
                        ['ko:'],
                        ['Eve Mesafe (m)'],
                        None,
                        None,
                        False)

def PlotFunction(xdata, xlabel, y1data, y1specs, y1label, y2data, y2label, Y2Axis):
    """
    Plot Function for LOG Data
    xdata = self.TimeMin
    xlabel = 'Zaman (dk)'
    y1data can be anything such as AGL list, Voltage etc.
    y1specs includes linecolor and linetype (dashed, dotted etc.)
    y1label for legends
    y2data is flight mode, current or something else
    y2label for legends
    Y2Axis is boolean if Y2Axis is exists.
    """
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(9,6.75, forward=True) # 4:3

    # Sub-Plot 1
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Axes 1 - Y1Data
    Lines = []
    for i in range(len(y1data)):
        temp = ax1.plot(xdata, y1data[i], y1specs[i], linewidth=3, label=y1label[i])
        Lines += temp
    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    #ax1.set_ylabel(y1label)

    # Axes 2 - Flight Mode
    if Y2Axis == True:
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        #ax2.set_ylabel(y2label)
        line4 = ax2.plot(xdata, y2data, label=y2label, 
                        color='#fb7d07',
                        linestyle='dotted',
                        marker='o',
                        markeredgecolor='#fb7d07',
                        markerfacecolor='#fb7d07',
                        markersize=4) # Color: Pumpkin Orange
        if y2data == CSV['ucus_modu']:
            FlightMode = ['YERDE', 'KALKIS', 'AYRILMA', 'SEYIR', 'KONUM', 'DONUS', 'INIS']
            ax2.set_yticklabels(FlightMode)
        Lines += line4

    # Set Legends
    labels = [l.get_label() for l in Lines]
    ax1.legend(Lines, labels, ncol = len(labels), loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.15))

    # Show Plot
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

PlotDistanceToHome()
```

Comment: You are asking about a button, but there is no button in the code. Chances are high that you will get an answer here when providing a [mcve], i.e. a code that can be run and which does not contain unnecessary stuff like `markeredgecolor` etc.

Comment: I think is about the matplotlib backend. I check the backend via 'matplotlib.getbackend' on both conda and python. The result of Python is 'TkAgg' and The miniconda result is 'Qt5Agg'. My approach is true?

Comment: The code you show is backend independent.

Comment: Finally, I solved. I just downgraded matplotlib version to 2.0.2 from 2.2.2. However, It should work on v2.2.2. I do not understand this weird behavior of v2.2.2.

Comment: As said, there is no button in the code and hence one cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for the next sample do not use sleep, use  matplotlib.pyplot.pause(interval)
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).